# would TLS prevent others reverse engineer my protocol?

Tags: security, networking, ssl, protocols

I'm working on a network program and I don't want anyone to know what kind of information is being passed when they sniff the network. Would using TLS achieve this? My main reason is that I want to keep the protocol I'm using to myself for now. If not please tell me if there is anything that can achieve my goal.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on a lot of things, e.g. what your exact threat model is, and how much information leakage you can tolerate.

For TLS to provide adequate protection, these assumptions must be true:

1. Obviously, you should use a correct implementation, otherwise, if for instance, you are using SecureTransport from iOS 7.0.4, all bets are off.
2. You should enforce a minimum version requirement and only support secure ciphersuites. If you allow downgrade to SSLv2, you are setting yourself up for problems.
3. You check for validity of the server public key. You'd be surprised how many client apps skip this.
4. You use client certificates to authenticate the client, as well as the server, otherwise, it is possible to write a phony client that talks to your TLS server and reverse engineer your protocol. (You can also authenticate the client early in the protocol lifecycle using other means, but that part of your protocol would not be safe).
5. You keep the private keys secure.
6. (If you are using X509 certificates and trust chains:) Certificate authorities that you trust do what they are supposed to do, i.e. not sign certificates in your name for others.
7. You will still leak some packet length and timing information that you hope would not be complete enough for the reverse engineer.
8. The attacker does not control your client or server or have access to the binaries on any side. If, like an iPhone app, you are giving away the client binary, you have already lost.
9. Your higher level protocol cannot be tricked into say, redirecting to another server blindly, or lose its mind and do some other crazy thing when the client secure channel is interrupted. This can be hard to notice at times and depends on many other factors.
10. Something else I have probably missed here.

Answer (score 1):

> Would TLS prevent others reverse engineer my protocol?

Probably not. Pentesters do it all the time. They use something like [Burp Suite](http://portswigger.net/burp/) to proxy the connection and watch all the web requests.

> If not please tell me if there is anything that can achieve my goal.

Common practice is: if you don't want it stolen, copied, pilfered, abused, etc, then you don't put it on a client. So all sensitive code and data goes on a server you control. Since the client gets to see the request, you have to remove all sensitive information from it.

Comment: You cannot MITM a TLS connection if both parties engage in mutual authentication and all you can do is to interfere with network traffic.  To proxy a TLS connection, you'll need your proxy to present a certificate satisfying the client.

Comment: @LeakyCode - But we can assume that someone attempting to reverse engineer a protocol controls the client-side, and can "tap into" the connection upstream of the client-side TLS.  Even if your server insists on client certificates, we can assume that the reverse engineer knows what they are ... 'code they are installed on >>his<< machine.

Comment: Not all mutual authentication requires a client certificate; for example, TLS-SRP and TLS_PSK. Client certificates are kind of rare in SSL/TLS because they are so broken in practice. In fact, mutual authentication is rare, too. I only recall one website using TLS-SRP.

Comment: @StephenC Not always.  Of course if the threat model assumes access to the client, reverse engineering would always be possible by looking at the binary, so you can't really do anything, but the question is still valid if both parties are trusted, and there is an active attacker on the network.

Comment: @LeakyCode - well, I doubt that the OP is really worried about the subcase of 3rd-party reverse engineering if 2nd-party reverse engineering is a cinch.  But, frankly the whole idea of trying to keep your wire protocols a secret is anachronistic and futile.  Security by obscurity does not work ...

Comment: @StephenC There are reasonable use cases for not wanting to leak what the underlying protocol is. Like, for instance, living in an oppressed country that drops encrypted connections that don't look like HTTPS. This paper might be of interest: https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/494.pdf

Comment: @LeakyCode - yea ... but that's not relevant to this question.